# Access to Category ID denied

Tags: php, fuel-sdk, content, fuel

I'm getting an error when trying to /*update*/ create a template using fuel php sdk.

```
$contentarea = new ET_ContentArea();
$contentarea->authStub = $etClient;
$contentarea->props = array("CategoryID"=>$contentFolder, "Name"=>$contentName, "Content"=> $localFile_contents);
$response = $contentarea->post();
```

From the output below the categoryID values match, but the error says it's denied. The same permissions are successfully being used to create the sub folder.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [StatusCode] => Error [StatusMessage]
=> Access to Category ID = 49009 denied. [OrdinalID] => 0 [ErrorCode] => 21006 
[NewID] => 0 [Object] => stdClass Object ( [PartnerKey] => [ObjectID] => [Content]
=> ["<p>hello world</p>"] [CategoryID] => 49009 [Name] => template) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access folder rather a content area, $contentFolder should be a "CustomerKey" (copy this from exactTarget contentarea->properties) and Name is optional as it only required if you want to change Name as well.

Would you try changing

```
$contentarea->props = array("CategoryID"=>$contentFolder.....
```

to

```
$contentarea->props = array("CustomerKey"=>$contentFolder
```

and

```
$contentarea->post();
```

to

```
$contentarea->patch();
```

I tried this and I am able to update the content area.

```
$myclient = new ET_Client();
    $ContentAreaUpdate = new ET_ContentArea();
    $ContentAreaUpdate->authStub = $myclient;
    $ContentAreaUpdate->props = array("CustomerKey" => "MYTestContentArea", "Content"=> "WOHOOOOOOOO! Love when things works");
    $ContentAreaUpdateResult = $ContentAreaUpdate->patch();
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fayyaz, what I'm trying to do is to  create a content area inside of a folder, not update an existing content area.
The code I've used works for adding content areas to some folders, but not other folders, even though the folders permissions have been set to have children and be written too.

Comment: I've updated my question from 'update' to 'create', sorry for the confusion.